# How to implement a single use ordered ReplaySubject?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, rx-scala

How can I have a single-subscriber `ReplaySubject` that:

1. buffers all events received with `onNext()` until someone subscribes to it,
2. once someone subscribes to it, all buffered events are forwarded to the subscriber, erasing them from the `ReplaySubject` buffer (for performance reasons) and subsequent events are only forwarded to the subscriber (no more buffering),
3. if more than one observer subscribes to it, an exception is thrown,
4. all buffered events given to the subject are ordered based on the time when each event was generated, and they are forwarded to the subscriber in that order during subscription?

Also, does this make sense? I think there would be good use cases for this subject, for cases when it forwards events from, e.g., a file system...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `UnicastSubject` for this purpose, although it's not part of the official API; that means it can change or get removed without warning.

**Edit**

Let me point you to the features you requested:

1) buffers all events:

[If there is no child or it hasn't caught up: store the element in the queue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L173):

2) When subscribed to, the buffer is consumed and replayed to the Subscriber

[The drain loop will poll from the queue and consume it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L287) and [if the Subscriber caught up, will emit to it directly](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L182).

3) if more than one observer subscribes to it, an exception is thrown

[A subsequent subscriber will get an exception](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L256)

4) all buffered events given to the subject are ordered based on the time when each event was generated

[Uses a single-producer single-consumer queue that guarantees FIFO order](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L148)

Comment: Of the 4 items that I mentioned, the UnicastSubject fulfills only item 3 (exception in case of more than 1 subscriber)... Perhaps there would be an easy way to implement such a subject from scratch, with all 4 items fulfilled?

Comment: What do you mean? Look at this line: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/UnicastSubject.java#L256

Comment: Precisely... That's item number 3, of the 4 that I proposed... The unicast subject does *not* implement 1, 2, or 4, so it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: How can you tell UnicastSubject doesn't implement all of your points?

Comment: It's not in the documentation, and if you read the source code, you won't see those features implemented there either.

Comment: Maybe you just don't recognize the features. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oops, you're right, and I just saw that you are the biggest contributor to rx. I apologize, my good sir :)